# Angular $http Respose Data is Undefined

Tags: angularjs, xml, http, response

I am trying to access an xml file from the server.
When I check in using code inspector the value of response.data is all set.
But the returned data is not reaching the controller.
In the controller. response.data is undefined.

```
fuseApp.factory('fuseHttpRequest', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var getRequest = function () {
            var xml;
            xml = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://vlandproperties.com/apitest/orders.xml',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
                },
                timeout: 10000,
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    return data;
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response.data
            });
        };
        return {
            getRequest: getRequest
        };
    }]);
```

[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8qHx.png)

Comment: are you sure that you need to return response.data and not just response in your .then() ?

Comment: I returned response. But I am not able to get the response data from that object. console.log gives f->$$state->status and value. I want this value. But don't know how to access it.

Comment: Please check the output added to post.